# Saving Data to mysql backend (POST) using retrofit in android

Tags: android, post, retrofit, backend

I am trying to post some data to backend in my app using retrofit. i tried a method to do so but data is not posted instead it is showing somw error, Below are my following classes:

1) ApiService Interface

```
public interface ApiService {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/enquiry.php")
Call<InsertData> insertFood(@Field("id")String id,@Field("Recipient_Email") String Recipient_Email, @Field("Subject") String Subject, @Field("Message") String Message);
}
```

2)InsertData.java

```
public class InsertData {
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("Recipient_email")
private String Recipient_email;
@SerializedName("Subject")
private String Subject;
@SerializedName("Message")
private String Message;

public InsertData(String id, String Recipient_email, String Subject, String Message) {
    this.id = id;
    this.Recipient_email = Recipient_email;
    this.Subject = Subject;
    this.Message = Message;
}

public InsertData() {
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setRecipient_email(String Recipient_email) {
    this.Recipient_email = Recipient_email;
}

public  void  setSubject(String Subject){
    this.Subject = Subject;
}

public void  setMessage(String Message){
    this.Message=Message;
}
}
```

3) MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnInsert;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnInsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtn_id);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Inserting");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ....");
    final EditText etRecipient = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recipient_id);
    final EditText etSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject_id);
    final EditText etMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message_id);
    final EditText etid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id2);
    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            progressDialog.show();
            String id= etid.getText().toString();
            String Recipient_Email = etRecipient.getText().toString();
            String Subject = etSubject.getText().toString();
            String Message = etMessage.getText().toString();
            insertData(id,Recipient_Email,Subject,Message);
        }
    });
}




/**
 * this method used to send data to server or our local server
 * @param  id
 * @param Recipient_Email
 * @param Subject
 * @param Message
 */
private void insertData(String id, String Recipient_Email, String Subject, String Message){
    ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
    Call<InsertData> call = apiService.insertFood(id,Recipient_Email, Subject,Message);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<InsertData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<InsertData> call, Response<InsertData> response) {

            InsertData insertData = response.body();

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"GONE :"+response.body().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<InsertData> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
}
```

I can't figure out what i am doing wrong. My onResponse method in MainActivity is showing following TOAST response:

**GONE: Response(protocol=h2,code=404,message=,url=here showing my url)**

and data is not posted to backend. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edits,

1) ApiClient.java

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String URL="https://pksinghhps.000webhostapp.com/asserts/";
public static Retrofit RETROFIT     = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(){
    if(RETROFIT==null){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor())
                .build();
        RETROFIT = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return RETROFIT;
}
}
```

2) enquiry.php

```
<?PHP

include("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['Recipient_email']) && 
isset($_POST['Subject']) && isset($_POST['Message']))
{
 $id=$_POST["id"];
 $Recipient_email=$_POST["Recipient_email"];
 $Subject=$_POST["Subject"];
 $Message=$_POST["Message"]; 
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM enquiries WHERE color = 
 '".$id."'"); 
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 { 
  echo "id exist";
  exit;
 } 
 else
 { 
  $query="INSERT INTO 
  enquiries(id,Recipient_email,Subject,Message)
  VALUES('$id','$Recipient_email','$Subject','$Message')";

  $data=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

  if($data)
  {
        echo "Successfully data sent";
  }
  else
  {
        echo "Error in sending data";
  }

  exit;
 } 
 } 

 ?>
```

Comment: Change this **@POST("/enquiry.php")** To **@POST("enquiry.php")**

Comment: Your api is working on postman

Comment: I used this in the  starting but hen it was giving error like " End of input at line 1 column 1 " then i used /enquiry.php then it was resolved.

Comment: If it is working fine on Postman  then post your ApiClient code and Logcat

Comment: @Prashantsingh maybe your json has some problem ? because Retrofit 2 accepts URL like the way i told you. [See Here](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: @KamalKakkar I don't have much knowledge about postman, i simply created a backend using PHP, if you want me to post my php code i can may be there is problem with php code

Comment: @AliAhmed I don't have much knowledge about postman, i simply created a backend using PHP, if you want me to post my php code i can may be there is problem with php code

Comment: @Prashantsingh edit your code and post . ApiClient class and PHP code.

Comment: @AliAhmed postman is client for check api is working correctly.So it is easily to check is it backend issue

Comment: I'm not OP :p and @Prashantsingh don't know how to use it.

Comment: edited the post and added both codes please do have a look

Comment: yes i dont know how to use Postman @KamalKakkar

Comment: **echo json_encode(array("success"=>"true","message"=>"Successfully data sent."));** AND in Error **echo json_encode(array("success"=>"false","message"=>"Failed to send data."));**

Add these to your PHP Code .. if and else staement

Comment: i'm not getting any response by calling your URL. it just return 200 status code. Means request is sent but nothing to return back

Comment: if($data)
      {
          echo json_encode(array("success"=>"true","message"=>"Successfully data sent.")); 
      }
    else
      {
            echo json_encode(array("success"=>"false","message"=>"Failed to send data."));
      }    like this ? @AliAhmed

Comment: yes. By adding this you will get response in JSON.

Comment: I have posted the solution. Hope so it will help you

Comment: @AliAhmed i know that by calling url doesnt give any response but this way worked for previously....... can you tell me what is wrong

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: @Prashantsingh if it helps you accept answer. If you still have problem,. Tell me.  Happy Coding !

Comment: nothing happened brother problem remains same  @AliAhmed

Comment: something really Strange happened here ... i just checked my database and it contains some data which was not added by me ...... have you tried something? @KamalKakkar

Comment: something really Strange happened here ... i just checked my database and it contains some data which was not added by me ...... have you tried something? @AliAhmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a little mistake here..

In your PHP code you have **Recipient_email** and in retrofit you're sending **Recipient_Email**

Change this

```
@POST("/enquiry.php")
Call<InsertData> insertFood(@Field("id")String id,@Field("Recipient_Email") String Recipient_Email, @Field("Subject") String Subject, @Field("Message") String Message);
```

TO

```
@POST("enquiry.php")
Call<InsertData> insertFood(@Field("id")String id,@Field("Recipient_email") String Recipient_Email, @Field("Subject") String Subject, @Field("Message") String Message);
```

**EDIT 1:**

Change your Model class

```
public class InsertData {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("Recipient_email")
    private String Recipient_email;
    @SerializedName("Subject")
    private String Subject;
    @SerializedName("Message")
    private String Message;
    @SerializedName("success")
    private String success;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message_resp;

    public InsertData(String id, String Recipient_email, String Subject, String Message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Recipient_email = Recipient_email;
        this.Subject = Subject;
        this.Message = Message;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRecipient_email() {
        return Recipient_email;
    }

    public void setRecipient_email(String recipient_email) {
        Recipient_email = recipient_email;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return Subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        Subject = subject;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return Message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        Message = message;
    }

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMessage_resp() {
        return message_resp;
    }

    public void setMessage_resp(String message_resp) {
        this.message_resp = message_resp;
    }
}
```

Comment: after your i thought i had made this stupid mistake but after correcting it nothing happened brother problem remains same  @AliAhmed

Comment: same i mentioned above Response: bla bla

Comment: something really Strange happened here ... i just checked my database and it contains some data which was not added by me ...... have you tried something?

Comment: This means my backend is working fine ? because the data you entered is saved in my backend

Comment: will making changes in InsertData.java foce me to make some changes in my MainActivity?

Comment: No. It is just to receive JSON response for your PHP code. so you can use that response in Java code e.g in onResponse() you can get Status **insertData.getStatus();**

Comment: hey, something great happened data is saved in backend and my toast is giving response ......"" Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept mailformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ ""

Comment: and even now i used @POST (enquiry.php) like the right way ... and it worked

Comment: Congrats . Accept answer, so it will help others too.

Comment: No Problem, My pleasure :)

Comment: I have one question that in onReponse i am showing TOAST with data saved and actually while running app it is showing  Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept mailformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ .... why so?

Comment: bcz your JSON is returning this too **<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
<b>/storage/ssd3/081/6935081/public_html/asserts/enquiry.php</b> on line
<b>13</b>
<br />**

Comment: hey listen what i just figured out .... my control is not reading onResponse instead it is going to onFailure and showing toast of onFailure

Comment: this query has some problem. run it on your server. maybe this solves your problem **$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM enquiries WHERE color = 
 '".$id."'");**

Comment: **SELECT id FROM enquiries WHERE color = $id"** you can also write it this way

Comment: hey broher i was some serious stupid mistakes now control is reading Onresponse method what  i did wrong was i used this **SELECT id FROM enquiries WHERE color = $id"** but i should be this **SELECT id FROM enquiries WHERE id = $id"**

Comment: i really committed  few stupid things man , made me ashamed of these mistakes -_-

Comment: No problem. Everyone learns from mistakes. i was wondering what is color. So thats great you've figured it out now,

Comment: Now finally i am using @POST("enquiry.php") and removed the code you gave me for InsertData.java , **so  as a conclusion the main problem was you answered in the starting in ApiService interface and after that  things are followed by my stupid mistakes.